# Подключение к удаленной базе через workbench

Tags: mysql

При попытке подключиться возникает вот такая ошибка:

> Host '128-75-158-36.broadband.corbina.ru' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Answer (score 1):

Если удаленный сервер ваш, то вам нужно создать пользователя, у которого есть права на удаленное подключение. См [Настройка удаленного подключения к MySQL](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/11.html)

Comment: Сервер на удаленное соединение настроил по этому руководству: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/mysql